# Interior lights aren't working, no power on ACC position

Tags: electrical, nissan, murano

**General Info**:

- Car: Nissan Murano 2005 SL
- Crank + start: Yes
- Battery charged: Yes
- Battery terminals correct install/uninstall order: Yes

**Problem**:

No power on ACC position, no ignition key warning sound, no ignition key light, no dome, map, rear interior lights, no rear windshield wiper.

**Works**:

Radio + dash on ON, windows, front windshield wiper, lock/unlock, door window buttons.

**Note**:

So my old battery got drained because I was messing around in the car for long without engine ON, and then since it wouldn't start, I jumpstarted the old battery to make sure that it was the problem. I replaced the battery with a new one, now all these problems started to occur. I should note that my friend was the one who jump started the old battery, so I'm unsure whether he followed the correct jumper order.

Additionally, when the key is on ACC, nothing in the dash lights up, I have to turn it into ON so the radio + dash turn on.

I have checked the fuses (using multimeter - continuity test), but not the relays.

[image]

This is the last fuse box which I have not throughly* checked, as accessing it has proven difficult. Is there any fuse(s)/relay(s) here that may be causing the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: 15A IGN & ECCS CONT

Comment: @narkeleptk Already checked 15A IGN & ECCS CONT fuse to no avail.

Comment: Your bcm may have got corrupted then. I see it happen quite a bit on Nissan's with battery issue's around that year. Is yours a key or twist ignition?

Comment: @narkeleptk Key.

Comment: Additionally, if the BCM was in some way messed up the behaviour of dash lights, etc. would be going all crazy--which does not happen. All works fine, it also remembers the time I left it in.

Comment: I was thinking maybe when the battery was removed, since there appears to not be any shorts, maybe it needs to be re-programmed somehow? I have also managed to track down most of the issues to a single cable but Idk where it is/how to access it since I'm not a mechanic... I found it on the car specifications (BCS) "GROUND" called "Room lamp harness" which is what all affected things get their power from

Comment: Specifically "M12" "R1"

Answer (score 0):

If absolutely nothing is working but you installed a brand new battery, first check to make sure the terminals are 100% clean and not corroded. If the connections are fine, check the main battery fuse - it should look like this

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to check them apart from visual inspection?

Comment: Also, only the interior lights are affected -- everything else works (dash, radio, a.c., etc.)

Comment: You can use a multimeter, but it's pretty easy to visually inspect. However, if some stuff works it definitely sounds like there's a fuse you missed, then

Comment: I have checked all fuses more than 3 times tho (using multimeter with continuity test), even removed them for visual inspection. I have however, managed to track down a possible culprit: https://i.ibb.co/CKYTJfF/image.png However I'm not even sure where this is located at all, or how I would check it.